# Piping PHP file content to PHP command in CLI

Tags: php, unix, curl, command-line-interface

My question relate to the use of PHP in CLI. I don't know why the piping of the content of a PHP file to the PHP command works:

```
    cat file.php | php
```

like in the installation of Composer [Composer Installation](http://getcomposer.org/download/):

```
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: uhh... `include()` or `file_get_contents()` or just `php file.php`. The pipe puts the file's contents into stdin, but the backticks and `cat` pass it as an argument, and PHP won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Why would you do it like this instead of `php file.php`?

Comment: I have just read the installation of composer through the pipe, and I wanted to know why it worked without the '-r'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't give any argument to PHP, it reads from standard input (commonly called `stdin`).
If your output buffering is disabled, you can try to run `php` without argument, and type `<?php echo "test\n";` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll see "test". `stdin` is **basically** the stream where your keyboard writes, and `stdout` is **basically** your terminal, where `echo` writes.

[image]

But the pipe ( `|` ) changes that behaviour : the standard output of the first program becomes the standard input of the second one.

[image]

This is a quite powerful thing our nix system shells offer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not do it that way and would simply execute the file by `php file.php`.  In this case, for whatever reason you want to do it that way, you need quotes around it with quotes

```
php -r "`cat file.php`"
```

**Edit** You could do this as well.

Put a hashbang at the front of the file like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env php 
<?php

//code follows here
```

Then execute with

```
cat file.php | php
```

Comment: This command wouldnt work on terminal for a PHP file which echo some text. It will issue:  `Could not open input file: <?php
    echo "hello world\n";`

Comment: I parsed a PHP file with no trouble before I posted it.  You might need to be clearer on the contents of your file to get much farther.

Comment: My file contains this: `<?php echo "hello world\n";`

Answer (score 0):

As to "why it works": It works because the -cli variant of the PHP binary is designed to read from `stdin` and process input scripts from there alternatively.

The manpage lists various execution options. See the very last line:

> PHP  is  a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is espe‐
>     cially suited for Web development and can be embedded into  HTML.  This
>          is the command line interface that enables you to do the following:
>
> You  can  parse and execute files by using parameter -f followed by the
>          name of the file to be executed.
>
> Using parameter -r you can directly execute  PHP  code  simply  as  you
>          would do inside a .php file when using the eval() function.
>
> It  is  also  possible to process the standard input line by line using
>    either the parameter -R or -F. In this mode each  separate  input  line
>    causes  the code specified by -R or the file specified by -F to be exe‐
>    cuted.  You can access the input line by $argn.  While  processing  the
>    input  lines  $argi  contains  the number of the actual line being pro‐
>    cessed. Further more the parameters -B and -E can be  used  to  execute
>    code  (see  -r)  before  and  after all input lines have been processed
>    respectively. Notice that the input is read from  STDIN  and  therefore
>    reading  from  STDIN  explicitly  changes  the next input line or skips
>    input lines.
>
> If none of -r -f -B -R -F or -E is present but a  single  parameter
>   is    given then this parameter is taken as the filename to parse and
>   execute    (same as with -f). **If no parameter is present then the 
>   standard  input    is read and executed.**

Comment: Most commandline interpreters do so. It's a common alternative to passing the file path as first parameter (all other PHP params / invocation methods are non-standard). And on some systems/shells, the shebang interpreter is run with the mentioned script on stdin instead of file path as first arg.